# Exchange server bulk email test setup

Tags: c#, email, exchange-server-2010

Hello and thank you for your help in advance,

I want to test a bulk email program I wrote with our exchange server.  I want to test real (not fake) email addresses that we have on file.  But I do not want the emails sent out to our customers.  I heard there is some way that our exchange server can be setup to send emails to a folder somehow.  But here is the twist - I need this test to only send emails to a folder if they are from a certain email address or ip address or something to filter out my testing from real people using the server on a regular daily basis.  Hopefully someone can help me out here.

Comment: So do you need help with how to send emails to a folder or how to filter email addresses?

Comment: you want to "test" the email addresses? what purpose would that serve?

Comment: @PeonProgrammer - Actually both - I am a programmer not a exchange server expert.  I do not want to disrupt our daily user activity - meaning if the setting to send to a folder is for everything - my idea wont work.

Comment: @user1666620 - It would help test my application.

Comment: what is the purpose of the test? what is it you are actually testing? what defines a successful test? that the emails are of valid format? that your application can send emails? also, you really should not be doing tests on live data on a live server.

Comment: @user1666620 - the purpose of the test would be to testing the functionality of my application on a real server.  The application I wrote simply sends out bulk emails to our customer - it has throttling settings that need to be tested.  Is there a fake free server out there that would serve this purpose?

Comment: ok. take a copy of the database, and restore it on a test server. change all the email addresses to be a test email account (or multiple accounts) controlled by you. point your application at this test database and send emails to those accounts using your exchange server.

Answer (score 0):

Do not test your application on a live server with live data of real people.

Instead, take a copy of the database, and restore it on a test server. Change all the email addresses to be a test email account (or multiple accounts) controlled by you. Point your application at this test database and send emails to those accounts using your exchange server.

If the emails are received, you have a successful test and can deploy your application to the live server.

Comment: What database are you referring to?  My application does not need one.  My application is on a test server.

Comment: @JohnAshton I assumed a database would store the email addresses you want to use. Where are you storing these email addresses? Just use email addresses that you own.

Comment: The app just lets a users copy paste either a comma delimited string or newline delimited string of emails.

Comment: so is your actual question to know if an email is a properly formatted email address or not?